# syntax error, unexpected 'define' (T_STRING)

Tags: wordpress

Don't know much coding, getting the captioned error when I try to visit my website / log in. Looking for a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi pshah, please provide significantly more detail on your problem to receive guidance.

Comment: My wordpress website, hosted on GoDaddy is throwing up this error when I try to visit or log in to it. 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'define' (T_STRING) in /home/content/69/7786769/html/wp-config.php on line 4

Answer (score 1):

You have to open wp-config.php and look at Line 4 because there is a php syntax error in the code in that file. If you want further details on how to fix please post the code from wp-config.php

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Different line number, but the same basic error message, which prevented the site from loading. There didn't seem to be anything wring with the code in wp-config.

I solved the issue by downloading a fresh copy of WordPress then using FTP to replace everything except the wp-config file and the wp-content folder. Your WordPress content lives in the wp-cntent folder so you don't want to replace that.

As soon as a replaced the other files. I refreshed the browser and the site loaded normally. I'm guessing somehow some crucial file became corrupted and that kept WordPress from loading.

The only WordPress file you should be editing is wp-config.  All your other data will be in wp-content or the MySql database. Retain the wp-content folder  and the wp-config.php file and replace everything else. It worked for me.